# Downloading file not showing total file size in liferay portlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, download, liferay-6

I am using serveResource to allow download files of document library through my portlet.

However, it only shows the downloaded size but not the size to be downloaded.

```
String mimetype = doc_file.getMimeType(); //doc_file is fileentry from document library       

if (mimetype == null) {           
    mimetype = "application/octet-stream";       
}
res.setContentType(mimetype); // res is ResourceResponse

res.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 
                " filename=\"" + 
                DocumentUtil.docNamingConvention(doc_file.getTitle(), "get") + 
                "." + doc_file.getExtension() + "\"" );
long zipFileLength = doc_file.getSize();
res.addProperty(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(zipFileLength));
FileInputStream  input = (FileInputStream) doc_file.getContentStream();
OutputStream out = res.getPortletOutputStream();

byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
int bytesread = 0, bytesBuffered = 0;
System.out.println(input.toString().length());
while((bytesread = input.read(buf)) > -1) {
    out.write(buf, 0, bytesread);
    bytesBuffered += bytesread;
    if (bytesBuffered > 1024 * 1024) { //flush after 1MB
        bytesBuffered = 0;
        out.flush();
    }
}
input.close(); 
out.close();
```

This code is working in Mozilla, Mozilla is showing total file size and size of data downloaded , but not in Internet Explorer and Chrome.

Comment: Are you talking about the value that the `println` outputs?

Comment: No.. size of download in browser... It is showing only size of file downloaded but not total size to be downloaded..

Comment: Well, I imagine that would be just down to differences in the respective browsers.